# When using slots, why does dir(type) have no __dict__ attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to understand slots. Therefore, I have written a little script with two classes, one using slots and one not.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

class C:
    __slots__ = "name"

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name
```

When I use the `dir()` on type `A` and on an object of type `A`, the attribute `__dict__` appears in the result list, as expected.

```
dir(A)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'getName']

dir(A("test"))
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'getName', 'name']
```

If I use type `C` I get

```
print(dir(C))
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'classAttributeC', 'getName', 'name']

print(dir(C("test")))
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'classAttributeC', 'getName', 'name']
```

No attribute `__dict__` in the results list for `dir(C("test"))`, as expected but also no attribute `__dict__` for `dir(C)`.
Why isn't the attribute in the results list when I can call `C.__dict__` and get the following output?

```
{'__module__': '__main__', 'classAttributeC': 9999, '__slots__': 'name', '__init__': <function C.__init__ at 0x7ff26b9ab730>, 'getName': <function C.getName at 0x7ff26b9ab7b8>, 'name': <member 'name' of 'C' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

Comment: I suspect that the `__dict__` attribute is created on the fly by the `__getattribute__` method when you use slots.

Comment: From the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes "Some of these are not reported by the dir() built-in function." Also another note https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir: "Note Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class."

Comment: @Barmar Why would you suspect that? The class itself still has a namespace (thats where its methods live), it's the instances whose namespaces are disabled by slots.

Comment: @wim It was just a guess for how the attribute was showing up if it's not in the class dictionary. I didn't know that `dir()` was selective as mentioned in flake's comment.

Comment: @Barmar Well, I think this guess is wrong because the namespace is still accessible using `inspect.getattr_static(C, "__dict__")` which [avoids invoking `__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getattr_static). Not sure why 2 ppl upvoted that comment!

Comment: @wim It's good I didn't post that as an answer. It just seemed like a possible way this was happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't override `__dir__` here, in each case here it will resolve in the MRO to `type.__dir__(A)` or `type.__dir__(C)`. So we look at the default implementation of `__dir__` for types, here in [`Objects/typeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L4168-L4190)

```c
/* __dir__ for type objects: returns __dict__ and __bases__.
   We deliberately don't suck up its __class__, as methods belonging to the
   metaclass would probably be more confusing than helpful.
*/
static PyObject *
type___dir___impl(PyTypeObject *self)
{
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    PyObject *dict = PyDict_New();

    if (dict != NULL && merge_class_dict(dict, (PyObject *)self) == 0)
        result = PyDict_Keys(dict);

    Py_XDECREF(dict);
    return result;
}
```

The bases are the same `(object,)`, so there is your answer in the `__dict__`:

```
>>> "__dict__" in A.__dict__
True
>>> "__dict__" in C.__dict__
False
```

So, types without slots implement a `__dict__` descriptor, but types which implement slots don't - and you just get a `__dict__` implementation from above:

```
>>> inspect.getattr_static(A, "__dict__")
<attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>
>>> inspect.getattr_static(C, "__dict__")
<attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects>
```